# Java sort based on two columns

Tags: java, sorting, multiple-columns

Lets say I have table like this:

```
 String | Int1 | Int2
 "foo"    5      0
 "faa"    4      1
 "zaa"    0      1
 "zoo"    4      2
 "laa"    4      3
 "loo"    1      4
```

What I would like to get is table like this:

```
 String | Int1 | Int2
 "foo"    5      0
 "laa"    4      3
 "zoo"    4      2
 "faa"    4      1
 "loo"    1      4
 "zaa"    0      1
```

First thing that happens is sort based on column `Int1`.

Second thing that happens is sort of based on column `Int2` but only on rows that have same numbers in column `Int1`

#### How should I approach this problem without using any database engine?

Comment: Why not just write your own compareTo()? Is this stored in a database?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'd normally do this with a `List<Item>` where `Item` is a type containing all three values ("foo", 5, 0 for the first row, for example).

You'd then write a `Comparator<Item>` which compared the Int1 values of the two `Item` objects presented to it in `compare`, and if that gave a definite answer, returned that answer... and otherwise compared the Int2 values.

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you have an object that has a String with 2 ints?

The easiest way to do this is to make the object implement `Comparable` and implement the `compareTo()` method. Or you can pass a Comparator to `Collections.sort(yourListOfObjects, yourCustomComparator)`

The compareTo() method will compare the first int first and if they are equal compare the second ints.

```
@Override
public int compareTo(MyObject o) {
    // compare int1s .. if equal, compare int2s and return 0,1 or -1
}
```

Here is a helpful link

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html

Answer (score 4):

It's rather unclear what you mean by table. But in the general case, you sort data in Java by using a `Comparator` or making your data structure implement `Comparable`. In your case you would create a simple data structure that encapsulates a row in your table, and then create a `Comparator` for the row data structure or have it implement `Comparable`.

For example

```
public class Row implements Comparable<Row> {
    public final String theString;
    public final int int1;
    public final int int2;

    public Row(String theString, int int1, int int2) {
        this.theString = theString;
        this.int1 = int1;
        this.int2 = int2;
   }

   public int compareTo(Row other) {
       if(this.int1 == other.int1) {
           return new Integer(this.int2).compareTo(other.int2);
       }

       return new Integer(this.int1).compareTo(other.int1);
   }
}
```

Then you would create a `List<Row>` and use `java.util.Collections.sort(List<?>)` to sort your data.

Answer (score 2):

If only Java supported lambdas ... this is trivial in so many languages.

But, hmm, let's see. Here are two general approaches (there are many different variations of these themes):

1. Create a new type with the members in question
2. Make the type implement `Comparable` (e.g. "compareTo")
3. Put elements of this new type into an Array or List (perhaps `List<NewType>`)
4. Use `Arrays.sort` or `Collections.sort` (or similar)

Or,

1. Create a nested array or List (perhaps `List<List<Object>>`)
2. Use `Arrays.sort` or `Collections.sort` (or similar) using the form that takes in a `Comparator`

Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

Well first define what you mean by a "table".

I would wrap each row within an object `Row` and keep an array of these `Row`s. Then you can either implement the `Comparable<Row>` interface or write your own `Comparator<Row>`.

So either:

```
...
class Row implements Comparable<Row> {
    String s;
    int int1, int2;

    ...

    public int compareTo( Row r ) {
        if( int1 != r.int1 ) return int1-r.int1;
        else return int2-r.int2;
    }
}
```

And call `Arrays.sort(rows);`

Or you can do this:

```
Arrays.sort(rows, new Comparator<Row>() {
    public int compare( Row r1, Row r2 ) {
        if( r1.int1 != r2.int1 ) return r1.int1-r2.int1;
        else return r1.int2-r2.int2;
    }
});
```

where `rows` is a `Row[]`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
public class Item implements Comparable<Item> {
    private String s;
    private Integer int1;
    private Integer int2;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Item o) {
        int compare = int1.compareTo(o.int1);
        return compare != 0 ? compare : int2.compareTo(o.int2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use a CompareToBuilder inside a Comparator implementation.

Example usage,

```
    new Comparator<YourObjectType>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(YourObjectType o1, YourObjectType o2) {
                return new CompareToBuilder()
                   .append(o1.firstFieldToCompare, o2.firstFieldToCompare)
                   .append(o1.secondFieldToCompare, o2.secondFieldToCompare)
                   .toComparison();
            }
        }
```